# SQL compilation error: syntax error line 21 at position 6 unexpected '@CPG'. syntax error line 21 at position 29 unexpected ','

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowsql

I am trying to create a new table in snowflake, but it is giving me the above error, how do i resolve this issue??
Does snowflaqke have problem with @ symbol while creating
Has anyone else encountered this issue??

```
CREATE  OR REPLACE  TABLE F58155
(  Rownum  NUMBER(8,0),
CA$CLC  NUMBER(8,0) , 
CA$CAT  VARCHAR(16777216),
CA$ATT VARCHAR(16777216),
CADSC1  VARCHAR(16777216),
CASY  VARCHAR(16777216),
CART  VARCHAR(16777216),
CA$SLT  VARCHAR(16777216),
CA$GRP  VARCHAR(16777216),
CA$MIN  NUMBER(8,0),
CA$MAX  NUMBER(8,0),
CAIEX  VARCHAR(16777216),
CA$VAL  VARCHAR(16777216),
CA$NBR  NUMBER(8,0),
CA$MAN  VARCHAR(16777216),
CAEFTJ  NUMBER(8,0),
CAEXDJ  NUMBER(8,0),
CA$ACT  VARCHAR(16777216),
CAUSRI  VARCHAR(16777216),
CA@CPG  VARCHAR(16777216),
CA@CJB  VARCHAR(16777216),
CACRDJ  NUMBER(8,0),
CATMCR  NUMBER(8,0),
CAUSER  VARCHAR(16777216),
CAPID  VARCHAR(16777216),
CAJOBN  VARCHAR(16777216),
CAUPMJ  NUMBER(8,0),
CATDAY  NUMBER(8,0)

);
```

Answer (score 2):

Snowflake is quite clear on the [requirements for an identifier](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html):

> Unquoted object identifiers:
>
> - Start with a letter (A-Z, a-z) or an underscore (“_”).
> - Contain only letters, underscores, decimal digits (0-9), and dollar signs (“$”).
> - Are case-insensitive.

The `@` is not allowed.  I would suggest you remove it.  Actually, I would replace both `@` and `$` with underscores.

But you can quote them if you prefer.